# How can I pass a variable to a WebComponent when it is created?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have a webcomponent `Login` that has a `LoginState` field.  I want to pass in a `LoginState` instance, which may be setup in some other part of the code, and add it to the `Login` instance before / during the created method.

Is this possible?  If not, what are my alternatives?  The only other one I can think of is to use a global variable that holds the `LoginState` instance and reference that, which doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible, when instantiating your component, use the syntax

```
<x-custom-element a-field-name="{{expression}}"></x-custom-element>
```

The expression will be evaluated and any field you have defined in the CustomElement class with the name `aFieldName` will be initialised with the value of `{{expression}}` ([see relevent discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/web-ui/ugxpNUW-oZA)). Personally I wouldn't suggest passing in something like your loginstate, as it would make your site incredibly vunerable to XSS attacks...

Perhaps a better idea would be to expose a method on your component class that allows you to set the login state after initialisation. After inserting the element into the DOM, you can access the fields of the element with `query('#myLoginStateId').xtag` and then call the exposed method with your login state.

You won't be able to access the xtag on the element until it's been inserted into the DOM, so make sure you raise an appropriate event in the element's inserted() method so the rest of your application knows when it is safe to set the appropriate field.

Comment: How would I go about raising that event?

Comment: try 
     void inserted() {
    var evt = new Event("load");
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

Register an onLoad event on the container of your element and check (evt.target.xtag) to make sure it's non-null. Ideally, you'd use a custom event type, but...